# Prove that the induced Spec map is continuous using the elementary open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I recently had a bunch of questions on a problem set that I could not solve and the instructor is not providing solutions.

Let $f: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism. Prove that the induced map $g: \text{Spec } B \to \text{Spec }A$ is continuous using elementary open sets only.

I can prove the continuity of the map using the closed set criterion, but I was restricted to use the elementary open sets only. The question asked to show that pre-images of the elementary open sets are open, and then obviously this proves the continuity of the map as these sets form a basis for the Zariski topology. Can someone give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: Hint: Let $q=f^{-1}(p)$ be some prime ideal not containing $x$. Then clearly $p$ doesn’t contain $f(x)$. Moreover, the converse holds as well.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by an elementary open set of $\text{Spec } A$?

Comment: An elementary open set of Spec A is D(f), the set of all prime ideals of A not containing f. Here f is an element of the ring A.

Comment: $f$ for an element of $A$ seems confusing as we already have used the symbol $f$ here.

Comment: He, you changed your name!

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about algebraic geometry, so going from definitions:

So consider what $g^{-1}[D(a)]$ is: it's the set of prime ideals $I$ in $B$ such that $g(I) \in D(a)$. $g(I) = f^{-1}[I]$ by the definition of the induced map (I think, it's the only definition that would make sense), so we consider all prime ideals $I$ such that $a \notin f^{-1}[I]$ (definition of $f^{-1}[I]$ to be in $D(a)$) which means in turn exactly that $f(a) \notin I$. So it seems to me that we have shown that $$g^{-1}[D(f)]= D(f(a))$$  which would be elementary open in $\text{Spec } B$. Seems something you could have figured out yourself, to me, at least.